# Grau de complexidade

Tags: python, algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo

```
def fRecursivo(n):
    if(n == 0 ):
        return 1
    if (n%2 ==1):
        return (n+3*fRecursivo(n-1))
    if(n%2 == 0 and n> 0):
        return (n+n+3*n*fRecursivo(n-1))
```

Qual o grau de complexidade do código para os números pares ? No caso quando for chamado a linha:

```
return (n+n+3*n*fRecursivo(n-1))
```

Answer (score 2):

Se `n` é par e maior que zero, é feita a chamada recursiva para `n - 1`, que é ímpar e portanto cai no segundo `if`.

Ali é feita outra chamada recursiva para `n - 1`, que é par (podendo ou não ser maior que zero).

Ou seja, para qualquer `n` maior que zero são feitas `n` chamadas recursivas, até que se chegue a zero.

Portanto a complexidade é O(n).